# Does iOS Prefix header only works for objective-c header files and not c's?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, cocoa, frameworks

I have two Cocoa Touch Framework projects.

First one have file structure like below:

```
|--sszip-Prefix.pch
|--ioapi.c
|--ioapi.h
```

Second one have file structure like below:

```
|--zipzap-Prefix.pch
|--ZZConstants.h
|--ZZConstants.m
```

The contents of the Prefix.pch file is the same:

```
#include <zlib.h>

#if defined(__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED)
#include <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
#elif defined(__MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED)
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

Both ioapi.h and ZZConstants.h need to use stuff in zlib.h

However when I compile both of them, the second project manage to compile without issues while the first project is having tons of Parse Issue errors unless I specifically insert #include "zlib.h" inside ioapi.h header file itself (though this gives another error, see bottom section)

The only difference I can see is ioapi.h is written in C while ZZConstants.h is written in objective-c

So the question is.. Does iOS Prefix header only works for objective-c header files and not c's? If so is there a workaround?

**The Back Story:**

The reason I need to use the Prefix header is because if I insert #include "zlib.h" directly in the header files, it gives error "Include of non-modular header inside framework module" in both cases.. somehow using the Prefix header won't have this issue.

And the main reason behind all this, is I'm trying to get [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) (a zip library) to work in Cocoa Touch Framework. I can use it in normal Swift project without issue using the bridging header, but somehow for Cocoa Touch Framework it's a totally different story!

PS: I'm trying to use [SSZipArchive](https://github.com/ZipArchive/ZipArchive) in the first project and [Zipzap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) in second project. Zipzap works but it is not very user-friendly.

Comment: You can use iOS frameworks directly now in ZipZap 8.0.4, you no longer have to construct your own prefix header. You should be able to `@import ZipZap` or `import ZipZap` and everything should work correctly.

Comment: As the author of ZipZap, I'd love to improve my library whenever possible. What do you find unfriendly about it?